# I wish to create Jagged arrays in Fortran but receives "There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘new’ at (1)"

Tags: fortran, jagged-arrays, allocatable-array

I wish to create jagged arrays in Fortran with multiple levels of allocation. However I run in to the error of "There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘new’ at (1)" for both my constructor and destructor procedures.

I'm quite new at Fortran. I believe the problem is my 1st argument "M1" doesn't fit. However, I can't seem to figure out why.

```
module JaggedArrayModule
  implicit none
  save
  private
  public JaggedArray, New, Delete

  type JaggedArray
    private
    real, allocatable               :: vector(:)
  end type

  interface New
    module procedure NewMatrix
  end interface

  interface Delete
    module procedure DeleteMatrix
  end interface

contains

  subroutine NewMatrix(Matrix, maxsize)
    type (JaggedArray), intent(out), allocatable   :: Matrix(:)
    integer                                        :: maxsize, i

    allocate(Matrix(maxsize))
    do i=1, maxsize
      allocate(Matrix(i)%vector(i))
    enddo
  end subroutine

  subroutine DeleteMatrix(Matrix, maxsize)
    type (JaggedArray), intent(inout), allocatable :: Matrix(:)
    integer                                        :: maxsize, i    

    do i=1, maxsize
      deallocate(Matrix(i)%vector(i))
    enddo
    deallocate(Matrix)   
  end subroutine

end module



program main
use JaggedArrayModule
type (JaggedArray) :: M1(5)

call New(M1, 10)
call Delete(M1, 10)


end program
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these case the best way to debug the error message is to call the actual specific subroutine. That means to call `NewMatrix` instead of `Matrix`.

Then you will get

```
 call NewMatrix(M1, 10)
               1
Error: Actual argument for ‘matrix’ must be ALLOCATABLE at (1)
jagged.f90:51:18:

 call DeleteMatrix(M1, 10)
                  1
Error: Actual argument for ‘matrix’ must be ALLOCATABLE at (1)
```

That is pretty much self-explanatory. `M1` must be `allocatable` to be passed to a subroutine that has an allocatable dummy argument. In modern Fortran generic disambiguation also considers the allocatable attribute. That is why you get the original error message.

---

Be aware that I get also this error for your code:

```
jagged.f90:37:17:

       deallocate(Matrix(i)%vector(i))
                 1
Error: Allocate-object at (1) must be ALLOCATABLE or a POINTER
```

You should use just

```
deallocate(Matrix(i)%vector)
```

However, the allocatable components are deallocated automatically. There is no need for a specialized (finalization) subroutine that does that.

The allocate statement

```
allocate(Matrix(i)%vector(i))
```

also probably wants some other size, and not `i`, but only you know that.